# css: overflowing when using translate in IE

Tags: html, css

I have the following webpage.

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
           <div class="content">Lot of contents</div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have the following css:

```
.container {
    height: 100vh;
}
.container .content {
    width: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

My aim is to center the .content in the screen. But this leads to overflow-x and -y in IE but not in Chrome and Firefox.

Is there any problems in my CSS?

Comment: Oh sorry, it is a typo, I use SASS mixin. I should write @include translate(-50%, -50%). But the problem remains the same.

Comment: if position:fixed , and position:relative are allowed - https://jsfiddle.net/y92dc12s/3/ (this looks ok in IE11, Firefox and Chrome). This is related somehow to position:absolute... and viewport units (maybe - in IE for sure)...

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue, but I was only dealing with the horizontal direction. I was able to solve the issue by using a positive percentage for translateX and using a negative percentage for 'left'.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to cause vertical overflow for me even in Chrome. In any case, I believe the issue is that the default 8px margin on `body` is causing the total height of your document to be (100vh + 16px), and causing the scrollbar to appear. The way to fix that would be to remove the default margin from the document like this:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

**Fixed Live Demo:**

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    height: 100vh;
}
.container .content {
    width: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Lot of contents</div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/y92dc12s/

This fixes the overflow on Chrome for me - tell me if it works in Internet Explorer!

Comment: This doesn't fix horizontal overflow in IE.

Comment: Fixes vertical overflow in Firefox and Chrome, at least. In IE11 - not.

Comment: When I look at the layout using Firefox, I get a strange result. The .content size is 1152x581px, and the position is top: 484px, left: 960px, right: -192px, bottom: -96px, It seems that the translate just translates the div but doesn't change the position of the div. I think this would explain overflow. There should be overflow but that doesn't show up in Chrome and Firefox but does in IE.

Comment: @CheungBrian Translate is indeed supposed to translate the div without changing its values for `position`.

Comment: Yes! If I use position fixed rather that position absolute, the problem seems to be gone.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why is this happening?

This behaviour is consistent across IE11 and the new IE Edge, and appears to be how IE handles the translate. If we remove the transform, we get this:

[image: Removed translate]

When we put the transform back, the overflow is still exactly the same:

[image: With translate]

IE treats the horizontal overflow the same, regardless of the transform.

#### Workaround

A possible workaround would be to make the `.container` `position: relative` and give it `overflow: hidden` (though this may not be desirable). Also remove the default margin and padding on the divs and body.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container .content {
  width: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: #F00;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Lot of contents</div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh sorry. I don't like putting overflow: hidden in css. If the screen size changes, viewer needs overflow to view more content.

Comment: It's not ideal, I am mainly outlining the **cause** of the problem and this is one possible workaround with a few caveats. It's worth noting that `position: fixed` will work, [but will not scroll with the page](https://jsbin.com/tehodowuto/1/edit).

Comment: @CheungBrian - Also, `position: fixed` will not allow the viewer to scroll the viewport to access overflowed content inside it :)

Comment: It seems I need to resort to javascript to detect whether there should be overflow dynamically

Comment: @CheungBrian - There could be other ways around this, but it depends entirely on your pages actual content. For instance you could center things differently, [like this example](http://jsbin.com/divisayole/edit?html,css,output)